# Can I send XRP to multiple addresses?

Tags: blockchain, xrp

I'm new to XRP devlopment and I was making an api for an exchange project with XRP and wanted to know that is XRP can be sent to multiple addresses?

Comment: Improved grammar

Answer (score 3):

No, it is currently not possible for a single transaction to send to multiple destination addresses. Instead, you should create one transaction for each destination. Be sure to increment the account sequence number (`Sequence`) so that each transaction sent from the same (source) account has a unique, sequential, monotonically-increasing sequence number.